# fwrite() : how to write nested structs

Tags: c++, struct, fwrite

I have the following structs defined in C++

```
// This is the record
typedef struct {
    unsigned int recid;
    unsigned int num;
    char str[STR_LENGTH];
    bool valid;  // if set, then this record is valid
} rec;

// This is the definition of a block, which contains a number of fixed-sized records
typedef struct {
    unsigned int blockid;
    unsigned int nreserved; // how many reserved entries
    rec entries[MAX_RECORDS_PER_BLOCK]; // array of records
    bool valid;  // if set, then this block is valid
} blk;
```

After data manipulation I want to write it to a file. `fwrite()` is the way to go. I have a function:

```
void WriteValidRecords(FILE *outfile, blk *buffer) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < buffer->nreserved; i++) {
        if (buffer->entries[i].valid) {
            // I think here is the mistake!!
            fwrite(&(buffer->entries[i]), 1, sizeof(rec), outfile);
        }
    }
}
```

witch writes the records 1 by 1 at a file. This compiles but what I get in the file is wrong. I think the pointer I pass as a first argument at `fwrite()` is the problem. But I've tried a lot of things and I can't seem to find what to put there.

I am not sure if it matters but this is how I call `WriteValidRecords()`:

```
blk *buffer = new blk[nmem_blocks];

temp = fopen(("temp", "wb");

// Do stuff

for (uint i = 0; i < nmem_blocks; i++) {
    WriteValidRecords(temp, &buffer[i], nios);
}
```

EDIT:

temp is opened in binary form.

Also I am on linux, yeah..

EDIT 2:

Ok i tried opening the file in both read and write mode and I think this should print what it reads. It does not. It prints the same thing again and again.

```
void WriteValidRecords(FILE *outfile, blk *buffer) {
    for (uint i = 0; i < buffer->nreserved; i++) {
        if (buffer->entries[i].valid) {
            fwrite(&(buffer->entries[i]), 1, sizeof(rec), outfile);
            fseek(outfile, -sizeof(rec), SEEK_CUR);
            rec tmp;
            fread(&tmp, 1, sizeof(rec), outfile);
            cout << tmp.recid << endl;
            cout << tmp.num << endl;
            cout << tmp.str << endl;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143362/discussion-on-question-by-the-gramm-fwrite-how-to-write-nested-structs).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming out of information you provided us with and assuming you use your code exactly like you described, I guess your problem is `fopen()`ing file in write-only mode. If you don't close the file and reopen it again in appropriate mode (i.e., `fopen(filename, "rb")`, `fread` won't read anything actually. In your code above, if you check return value of `fread`, you'll see that it's zero.

Either change opening mode to `"w+b"` or reopen the file in appropriate access mode for reading data back.

Comment: Thanks, I found the problem. It's way deeper than I thought, your input helped a lot tho. The code above works as it should. The mistake is made elsewhere.

Comment: lol. Anyways, glad it helped somehow.